# React Hooks clickhandler to children

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello I have a clickhandler that I send to a child component and use it on onclick, but for some reason, my click handler event on my parent component is not running

parent jsx:

```
type ClickHandler = (tag: ITag) => (e: MouseEvent) => void

const MenuTags: React.FC<{hover: boolean}> = observer(({hover}) => {
  const {layoutStore} = useRootStore()
  const [tags, setTags] = useState<ITag[]>(Tags)
  const showHideDropItem: ShowHideDropItem = (tag) => {
    console.log(tag)
    setTags((items) =>
      items.map((item) => ({
        ...item,
        Active: item.Name === tag.Name ? tag.Active !== true : false,
      })),
    )
  }

  const clickHandler: ClickHandler = (tag) => (e) => {
    console.log('a')
    e.preventDefault()
    showHideDropItem(tag)
  }

  return (
    <MenuList
      open={layoutStore.sideBar || layoutStore.onHoverSideState}
      hover={hover}
    >
      {tags.map((item) => (
        <div key={JSON.stringify(item.Name)}>
          {item.Title ? <div className="title_tagList">{item.Title}</div> : ''}
          <TagList
            open={layoutStore.sideBar || layoutStore.onHoverSideState}
            tag={item}
            clickHandler={clickHandler}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </MenuList>
  )
})
```

my children jsx:

```
const TagList: React.FC<ITagList> = observer(({tag, clickHandler, open}) => {
  const tagHandleClick = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (tag.Active !== undefined) clickHandler(tag)
  }
  return (
    <ListItem open={open} isDropDown={!!tag.DropdownItems} active={tag.Active}>
        <div className="tag-container">
          <NavLink
            className="tag-wrapper"
            to={tag.Link}
            onClick={tagHandleClick}
          >
            <tag.Icon className="svg-main" size={22} />
            <span className="tag-name">{tag.Name}</span>
          </NavLink>
        </div> 
    </ListItem>
  )
})
```

when clicking on my event it enters my handler of the child component, but the handler does not call my parent component's handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `clickHandler` is a function that returns a function. It might be easier to see if you temporarily rewrite it like this:

```js
const clickHandler: ClickHandler = (tag) => {
  return (e) => {
    console.log("a")
    e.preventDefault()
    showHideDropItem(tag)
  }
}
```

Instead of returning a function you could just do the logic of the inner function directly instead.

```js
const clickHandler: ClickHandler = (tag) => {
  console.log('a')
  showHideDropItem(tag)
}
```